# Spark java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, ioerror

I have the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
```

When I execute the following line:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("file://home/test.json")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how did you "execute" the line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load data from local please use

```
sqlContext.read.json("file:///home/shankar/test.json")
```

or just

```
sqlContext.read.json("/home/shankar/test.json")
```

will work

If you want to load the file from HDFS use

```
sqlContext.read.json("hdfs:///user/shankar/test.json")
```

Hope this helps!