# java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/data/home/test/analysis.json does not exist. Spark error while reading json

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to write a json file from a spark/scala program and then read it into a DataFrame. This is my code:

```
 val analysisWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("analysis.json"))
 for(i <- 0 to 10){
         val obj =  arr.get(i).asInstanceOf[JSONObject]
         currentAnalysis(""+obj.get("id"))
    }
    analysisWriter.close()
    val df = hiveContext.read.json("file:///data/home/test/analysis.json")
    df.show(10)

  }   

  def currentAnalysis(id: String): Unit= {
     val arrCurrentAnalysis: JSONObject = acc.getCurrentAnalysis(""+id)

     if(arrCurrentAnalysis != null) {
       analysisWriter.append(arrCurrentAnalysis.toString())
       analysisWriter.newLine()
  }
```

I get the following error when I try to run this code:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/data/home/test/analysis.json does not exist
```

I can see the file being created in the same directory where the jar(I am running the jar using `spark-submit`) is present. Why is the code not able to find the file?

Initially, I was getting `java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job`

As pointed out here : [Spark SQL "No input paths specified in jobs" when create DataFrame based on JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150311/spark-sql-no-input-paths-specified-in-jobs-when-create-dataframe-based-on-json)

and here: [Spark java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800187/spark-java-io-ioexception-no-input-paths-specified-in-job) ,

I added `file://` to the path to read the json file from and now I get the `FileNotFoundException`.

I am running `spark 1.6` on a `yarn` cluster. Could it be the case that the file is not being available to the executors as it was created after the program has been launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I guess I am right about the file not being available to all the executors. I was able to solve it by copying the file onto a location in HDFS. I don't see the error anymore. I added the following lines to the code:

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://nameservice1"), sc.hadoopConfiguration)

fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("local_path"), new Path("hdfs_path"))
```

and then provided the hdfs_path to `hiveContext.read.json()`

It is able to create the Dataframe without any issues now.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, your application depends on a local file for some of its business logics.

We can read the file by referring to it as file:///. But for this to work, the copy of the file needs to be on every worker or every worker need to have access to common shared drive as in a NFS mount.

So to solve this you could use `spark-submit` provides the `--files` tag to upload files to the execution directories. If you have small files that do not change.

Alternatively as the others have suggested put it in HDFS

Answer (score -1):

We can also get this error message when we have "white spaces" in path file or filenames (i.e. /Folder1/My Images/...).

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/.../314_100.jpg does not exist
```

My case reading files with spark.
Replace "My images" with "My_images" and it should be ok.